# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list) error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am doing a course on Natural Language processing using TensorFlow on coursera. In one of the labs, we have to explore overfitting in NLP. I am continuously getting the same error while running the model. The error is

```
Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

Here is the code. I think something is wrong with `train_labels` and `val_labels`. I tried using `.astpye()` but, it gives an error `setting an array with a sequence`.

```
import csv
import random
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import linregress

EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
MAXLEN = 16
TRUNCATING = 'post'
PADDING = 'post'
OOV_TOKEN = "<OOV>"
MAX_EXAMPLES = 160000
TRAINING_SPLIT = 0.9

SENTIMENT_CSV = "./data/training_cleaned.csv"

with open(SENTIMENT_CSV, 'r') as csvfile:
    print(f"First data point looks like this:\n\n{csvfile.readline()}")
    print(f"Second data point looks like this:\n\n{csvfile.readline()}")

def parse_data_from_file(filename):

    sentences = []
    labels = []
    
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        ### START CODE HERE
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
            sentences.append(row[5])
            if row[0] == '0':
                labels.append(0)
            else:
                labels.append(1)
                
            labels.append(labels)
                
        ### END CODE HERE
        
    return sentences, labels


sentences, labels = parse_data_from_file(SENTIMENT_CSV)

print(f"dataset contains {len(sentences)} examples\n")

print(f"Text of second example should look like this:\n{sentences[1]}\n")
print(f"Text of fourth example should look like this:\n{sentences[3]}")

print(f"\nLabels of last 5 examples should look like this:\n{labels[-5:]}")

sentences_and_labels = list(zip(sentences, labels))

# Perform random sampling
random.seed(42)
sentences_and_labels = random.sample(sentences_and_labels, MAX_EXAMPLES)

# Unpack back into separate lists
sentences, labels = zip(*sentences_and_labels)

print(f"There are {len(sentences)} sentences and {len(labels)} labels after random sampling\n")

def train_val_split(sentences, labels, training_split):

    train_size = int(len(sentences) * training_split)

    # Split the sentences and labels into train/validation splits
    train_sentences = sentences[:train_size]
    train_labels = labels[:train_size]

    validation_sentences = sentences[train_size:]
    validation_labels = labels[train_size:]
    
    ### END CODE HERE
    
    return train_sentences, validation_sentences, train_labels, validation_labels

train_sentences, val_sentences, train_labels, val_labels = train_val_split(sentences, labels, TRAINING_SPLIT)

print(f"There are {len(train_sentences)} sentences for training.\n")
print(f"There are {len(train_labels)} labels for training.\n")
print(f"There are {len(val_sentences)} sentences for validation.\n")
print(f"There are {len(val_labels)} labels for validation.")

def fit_tokenizer(train_sentences, oov_token):


    tokenizer =  Tokenizer(oov_token="<OOV>")
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_sentences)
    
    # Fit the tokenizer to the training sentences
    
    
    ### END CODE HERE
    
    return tokenizer

tokenizer = fit_tokenizer(train_sentences, OOV_TOKEN)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
VOCAB_SIZE = len(word_index)

print(f"Vocabulary contains {VOCAB_SIZE} words\n")
print("<OOV> token included in vocabulary" if "<OOV>" in word_index else "<OOV> token NOT included in vocabulary")
print(f"\nindex of word 'i' should be {word_index['i']}")

def seq_pad_and_trunc(sentences, tokenizer, padding, truncating, maxlen):


    sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences)
    
    # Pad the sequences using the correct padding, truncating and maxlen
    pad_trunc_sequences = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=maxlen, padding = padding, truncating=truncating)
    
    ### END CODE HERE
    
    return pad_trunc_sequences

train_pad_trunc_seq = seq_pad_and_trunc(train_sentences, tokenizer, PADDING, TRUNCATING, MAXLEN)
val_pad_trunc_seq = seq_pad_and_trunc(val_sentences, tokenizer, PADDING, TRUNCATING, MAXLEN)

print(f"Padded and truncated training sequences have shape: {train_pad_trunc_seq.shape}\n")
print(f"Padded and truncated validation sequences have shape: {val_pad_trunc_seq.shape}")

train_labels = np.asarray(train_labels)
val_labels = np.asarray(val_labels)

GLOVE_FILE = './data/glove.6B.100d.txt'

# Initialize an empty embeddings index dictionary
GLOVE_EMBEDDINGS = {}

# Read file and fill GLOVE_EMBEDDINGS with its contents
with open(GLOVE_FILE) as f:
    for line in f:
        values = line.split()
        word = values[0]
        coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
        GLOVE_EMBEDDINGS[word] = coefs


EMBEDDINGS_MATRIX = np.zeros((VOCAB_SIZE+1, EMBEDDING_DIM))

# Iterate all of the words in the vocabulary and if the vector representation for 
# each word exists within GloVe's representations, save it in the EMBEDDINGS_MATRIX array
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = GLOVE_EMBEDDINGS.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        EMBEDDINGS_MATRIX[i] = embedding_vector

def create_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, maxlen, embeddings_matrix):


    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size+1, embedding_dim,input_length=maxlen, weights=[embeddings_matrix],trainable=False),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(1000, 1), return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')
    ])
    
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics='accuracy') 

    ### END CODE HERE

    return model

model = create_model(VOCAB_SIZE, EMBEDDING_DIM, MAXLEN, EMBEDDINGS_MATRIX)
history = model.fit(train_pad_trunc_seq, train_labels, epochs=1, validation_data = (val_pad_trunc_seq,val_labels))
```

Error shown:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the `parse_data_from_file()` function which is creating incorrect labels. Kindly change it like below;

```
def parse_data_from_file(filename):

    sentences = []
    labels = []

    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        ### START CODE HERE
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            label = int(row[0]) /4
            label = int(label)
            labels.append(label)
            sentence = row[5]
            sentences.append(sentence)


        ### END CODE HERE

    return sentences, labels
```

Please find the working code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/1dbc6da7ed58d7306b8086e215ded39d/74550639.ipynb#scrollTo=O28Cyup-Jcti). Thank you!